# How to schedule a pentaho transformation/job using crontab

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Can anyone please provide me a step by step procedure for scheduling a pentaho job/transformation using crontab.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge first you need to create shell script to run pentaho jobs or transformation, whatever it is.

Once you create a shell file then you have to call this file with the required arguments, if any.

Then you can schedule this scripting file using crontab.

```
0 5,17 * * * /scripts/script.sh
```